# Transposing selectively in pandas (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to create a two-way table with the data i have (sample data below)

```
      hour               source       Group_Count

       1            bloomberg            1
       1          motley fool            1
       1              reuters            1
       1                zacks            4
       2          motley fool            1
       2              reuters            3
       2                zacks            6
       3          motley fool            1
       3              reuters            4
```

i want a table which somewhat looks like this

```
            bloomberg    motley fool    reuters   zacks
hour

1               1             1            1        4
2               0             1            3        6 
3               0             1            4        0
```

getting the `0`'s in empty places is not mandatory. I know pandas will automatically set it as `NAN`. is this possible to do in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='hour', columns='source', values='Group_Count').fillna(0))
source  bloomberg  motley fool  reuters  zacks
hour                                          
1             1.0          1.0      1.0    4.0
2             0.0          1.0      3.0    6.0
3             0.0          1.0      4.0    0.0
```